# Carto.js - Change infowindow field on click event

Tags: leaflet, carto, carto-js, infowindow

How can I get fields in an infowindow to change when I click on something?

For example, if this is my infowindow code:
`cartodb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, layer.getSubLayer(0), ['abbrev'])`
How can I change the column `abbrev` to `cartodb_id` when I click on a button, and have the new field appear in the infowindow when clicking on a map feature. I think it should be easy, but so far I haven't found a way to do this successfully.

Here's a jsfiddle I'm experimenting with:

https://jsfiddle.net/Sidders/cb40w5ku/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the `cartodb_id` interactivity in your `layer_source` variable:

```
var layerSource = {
      user_name: 'examples',
      type: 'cartodb',
      sublayers: [{
         sql: 'select * from country_boundaries',
         cartocss: '#layer { polygon-fill: #F00; polygon-opacity: 0.3; line-color: #F00; }',
         interactivity: ['cartodb_id', 'abbrev']
      }]
  }
```

Then you can update your `infowindow_fields` as `['cartodb_id']`. The infowindow will show the `cartodb_id` of the selected feature.

UPDATE: after realizing it was a problem of scope, this is the code that will work:

```
            jQuery(function($) {

            //default infowindow fields
            var infowindow_fields = ['abbrev'];

            // create leaflet map and define some properties
            var map = L.map('map', { 
              zoomControl: false,
              center: [43, 0],
              zoom: 3
            })

            // add a base layer to map   
            L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
              attribution: 'Stamen'
            }).addTo(map);

            // Create button to change infowindow field on click



        // Put layer data into a JS object
    var layerSource = {
          user_name: 'examples',
          type: 'cartodb',
          sublayers: [{
             sql: 'select * from country_boundaries',
             cartocss: '#layer { polygon-fill: #F00; polygon-opacity: 0.3; line-color: #F00; }',
             interactivity: ['cartodb_id', 'abbrev']
          }]
      }

        var options = { https: true }

             // add cartodb layer with one sublayer
            cartodb.createLayer(map, layerSource, options)
            .addTo(map)
            .done(function(layer) {
              var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
              console.log(sublayer);
              cartodb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, sublayer, infowindow_fields);
              var createSelector = function() {
                console.log(sublayer)
                  var $options = $(".layer_selector").find("li");
                  $options.click(function(e) {
                      var $li = $(e.target);
                      selected = $li.attr('data');
                      infowindow_fields[0] = selected;
                      console.log(infowindow_fields[0]);
                      sublayer.setInteraction(false);
                      sublayer.off();
                      sublayer.setInteractivity(selected);
                      cartodb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, sublayer, infowindow_fields);

                    });


              }();


            });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ramiroaznar - unfortunately however, adding your above code still doesn't result in the 'cartodb_id' field showing up when you click on the button. The infowindow still comes up blank :(

Unless there's a way to force the infowindow field to appear?

Comment: It is working on my side with the fiddle you have shared. Have you tried to apply the changes I suggested and refresh the site? Or running on a local server?

Comment: How bizarre. I've revised the fiddle to include your code (link below), which I've also hard-refreshed a few times, but I still get a blank infowindow after clicking on the button: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Sidders/cb40w5ku/9/)

Comment: You have to replace in line 4 the field you want to interact to `var infowindow_fields = ['cartodb_id'];`. After that refresh your browser.

Comment: Okay. I changed `var infowindow_fields = ['abbrev'];` to `var infowindow_fields = ['cartodb_id'];`, however that changes the infowindow field before loading the map. Instead I want to change the field `['abbrev']` to `['cartodb']` after clicking on a button. I hope that makes more sense.

So to do this I've tried to explicitly set `infowindow_fields[0]` to the `selected` variable, which contains the field I want, in the click function (see jsfiddle link in the original post). But this doesn't work. I'd be grateful to know why and how to fix that?

I hope that solves any misunderstanding :)

Comment: There is a problem of (function) scope. I have update my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for giving this another go. I agree there's likely a scope issue. Unfortunately though by putting the infowindow `cartodb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, sublayer, infowindow_fields);` code inside the `click` function, the infowindow doesn't work when the map loads until the button is clicked. But it will work if it is put in the createSelector variable, except the changed infowindow field will be empty again.

So I guess we need to figure out how to set the `infowindow_fields` variable in a click function, and return the value so it works with the infowindow code?

Comment: Well, now that you know it is a problem of scope you can do the research. Try and error. Good luck!

Comment: Yes I had and failed. Which is why I came here. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47008/discussion-between-ramiroaznar-and-sidders).

Comment: Thanks @ramiroaznar for sending your amended code. It does work and but I'll still see if there is a more 'elegant' solution (e.g. dynamic mustache templates). Anyhow, if/when you have time, would you mind explaining the thinking behind the changes you made? (e.g. `sublayer.setInteraction(false);` `sublayer.off();` `sublayer.setInteractivity(selected);` )